# Termcaps : Get cursor position

Tags: c, shell, unix, iterm2, termcap

I need to get my (Y, X) position of my terminal's cursor with the termcaps in C.

With `ioctl()` i get the size of my terminal screen, but i still need to get where my cursor is.

I found this :

> CSI 6 n DSR – Device Status Report Reports the cursor position to the
>   application as (as though typed at the keyboard) ESC[n;mR, where n is
>   the row and m is the column. (May not work on MS-DOS.)

But i have no idea how to use it in C ...

Comment: Take a look [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write the command sequence (`<ESC>[6n`) to the terminal using normal output to `stdout`. Then you read the response using normal input from `stdin`.

You need to parse the "reply" to pick out the position.

Answer (score -3):

here is a `gotoxy()` function, that can print on specified **x** and **y** position in gcc linux

```
#include<stdio.h>
//gotoxy function
void gotoxy(int x,int y)
{
printf("%c[%d;%df",0x1B,y,x);
}
main ()
{
gotoxy(25,50); //reposition cursor
printf("hello world"); //display text
}
```

here is a reference for **console input and output** , if you are using terminal for windows (dos prompt)

Comment: -1 He wants to get the location of the cursor, not set the location, I advise you to edit that so it wouldn't be downvoted by others.

Comment: Or just delete it, since it's completely irrelevant to the question.