# Python Linux Console - Get cursor position

Tags: python, linux, console, command-line-interface

The title of the post is self-explanatory.
I wanna know how can I take the Linux terminal cursor position.

For instance, I'm currently setting the position like so:

```py
print('\033[10;10f')
```

Comment: Have you looked at the Python curses module which provides an interface to the `ncurses`  library, the de-facto standard for portable advanced terminal handling on Unix and Unix-like OSes?

Comment: @fpmurphy Yeah, I looked, but `ncurses` clears the console buffer, and i don't wanna it

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34746712/14772619

Comment: After some more research I found the correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46675451/15286947).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I found the correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46675451/15286947). And after some fixes it ended like so:

```py
import re, sys, termios, tty

def getpos():
  buff = ''
  stdin = sys.stdin.fileno()
  tattr = termios.tcgetattr(stdin)

  try:
    tty.setcbreak(stdin, termios.TCSANOW)
    sys.stdout.write('\033[6n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

    while True:
      buff += sys.stdin.read(1)
      if buff[-1] == 'R': break
  finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(stdin, termios.TCSANOW, tattr)

  matches = re.match(r'^\033\[(\d*);(\d*)R', buff)
  if matches == None: return None

  groups = matches.groups()
  return (int(groups[0]), int(groups[1]))
```